# SharePoint Server 2013 installation

Tags: sharepoint-server

Do we first need to install SharePoint Server Standard 2013  and then install SharePoint Server 2013 Standard with SP1 or else we can directly install SharePoint Server 2013 Standard with SP1

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are doing a fresh installation, so you can go ahead and install SP2013 With SP1 . Let me know if not

Comment: yes, i am installing new sharepoint 2013 farm... thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install sharepoint and service pack separately. Simply install sharepoint server with SP1 and after that apply the latest cu, so that you farm will be uptodate.